# Populate a specific column in a csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

As the title says, I want to populate a specific column in a CSV file by appending to the bottom of it.

Let's say we have a CSV table (`file.csv`) that looks like this:

```
     A       B        C              D
1 "text"   "word"  "phrase"       "term"
2 "number" "digit" "amount"       "numeral"
3 "letter" "char"  "hieroglyphic" "symbol"
```

In my PowerShell script, I have:

```
$foo = "x"

Out-File -FilePath file.CSV -Append -InputObject $foo
```

The result is this:

```
     A       B        C              D
1 "text"   "word"  "phrase"       "term"
2 "number" "digit" "amount"       "numeral"
3 "letter" "char"  "hieroglyphic" "symbol"
4   "x"
```

How do I get the value of `$foo` into a specific column such as C (below)?

```
     A       B        C              D
1 "text"   "word"  "phrase"       "term"
2 "number" "digit" "amount"       "numeral"
3 "letter" "char"  "hieroglyphic" "symbol"
4                    "x"
```

Comment: Try `$foo=("","","x","")`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried that and "x" got put into A6.

Answer (score 1):

Let the value of the column number(starting with index 0) where you want the value be stored be in the variable column_number

```
$column_number = 1
```

You can use the `Add-Content` command as follows

```
Add-Content .\file.CSV -Value "$(","*$column_number)$foo"
```

This will append the value stored in `$foo` at the specified column number. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-6) is the documentation for the Add-Content command.

Comment: You can use any command. Just replace $foo with "$(","*$column_number)$foo"

Comment: This is great. Thank you. When I tried a value of 1 for $column_name, the x populated in column B (cell B4), which was expected. 

When I changed the value to 2, the x populated in C. Again, expected. However, it skipped row 4 and populated in C5, leaving an empty C4.

Just so I don't run into issues with that, do you know a way to enhance the already great work you've provided to prevent that?

Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just assumed you wanted to add a value as specified in your example. For proper manipulations, you could always use the `Import-Csv` command. This will load the csv into a variable. You can now easily add values and export it back to a csv. [Here](https://ss64.com/ps/import-csv.html) is a simplified reference .